# Show-Hide warning is delayed in contact form

Tags: javascript, forms, show-hide

The contact form that I am setting up has a drop down menu area for the timeframe. The choices are: 
1. Normal Pace 
2. Speedy Pace 
3. Urgent Pace.

I have it set up to whenever speedy or urgent are chosen a warning will appear telling the user that the price will go up with those choices. However this warning is delayed until the user clicks on the second drop down menu (budget). Is there anyway I can make it pop up right after they choose those one of two options or no?

Whole code:

HTML

```
     <div id="primary" class="col-md-6">    
     <div id="form-wrap">
         <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $newToken; ?>" >

           <div class="rowElem">
            <ul><li><h5 class="formtitle">Your Name:</h5></li></ul>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="required" name="name" placeholder="Name" minlength="2" />
            </div><!-- End rowElem -->

          <div class="rowElem">
            <ul><li><h5 class="formtitle">Best Way to contact you:</h5></li></ul>

                <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contactemail" value="Email" />
                <label for="email">Email:</label><br /><br />
                        <div id="emailArea"> 
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                        </div>  

                <input type="radio" name="contact" id="contactphone" value="Phone" />                   
                <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br /><br />

                        <div id="phoneArea">
                        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
                        </div>       
            </div><!-- End rowElem -->



          <div id="projectList">
          <ul><li><h5 class="formtitle">Projects:</h5></li></ul>
          <h6>See more in detail <a href="services.html">here</a>.</h6>

          <div id="rowElem">
          <input type="checkbox" name="project" id="addWeb" value="website" />
          <label for="website"> Websites</label>
                <div id="addWebArea">   
                <input type="checkbox" name="web" value="develop" />
                <label for="website" class="checkedform"> Design</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="web" value="design" />
                <label for="website" class="checkedform"> Develop</label>
                </div>
          </div><!-- End rowElem -->

          <br /><br />
          <div id="rowElem">
          <input type="checkbox" name="project" id="addGraphic" value="graphic" />
          <label for="graphic"> Graphics</label>
                <div id="addGraphicArea">
                <input type="checkbox" name="graphics" value="branding" />
                <label for="graphic" class="checkedform"> Branding</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="graphics" value="posters" />
                <label for="graphic" class="checkedform"> Posters</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="graphics" value="other" />
                <label for="graphic" class="checkedform"> Other</label>
                </div>
          </div><!-- End rowElem -->

          <br /><br />
          <div id="rowElem">
          <input type="checkbox" name="project" id="addApp" value="app" />
          <label for="app"> Apps</label>
                <div id="addAppArea">
                <input type="checkbox" name="apps" value="Develop" />
                <label for="app" class="checkedform"> Develop</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="apps" value="Design" />
                <label for="app" class="checkedform"> Design</label>
                </div>
          </div><!-- End rowElem -->

          <br /><br />
          <div id="rowElem">
          <input type="checkbox" name="project" id="addPres" value="presentations" />
          <label for="presentation"> Presentations</label>
                <div id="addPresArea">
                <input type="checkbox" name="presentation" value="business" />
                <label for="presentation" class="checkedform"> Business</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="presentation" value="event" />
                <label for="presentation" class="checkedform"> Event</label>
                </div>
          </div><!-- End rowElem -->

          <br /><br />
          <div id="rowElem">
          <input type="checkbox" name="project" id="tut" value="tutorials" />
          <label for="tutorial"> Tutorials</label>
          </div><!-- End rowElem -->

          <br /><br />
          <div id="rowElem">
          <input type="checkbox" name="project" id="addOther" value="other" />
          <label for="other"> Other</label>
                <div id="addOtherArea"> 
                <label for="other" class="checkedform"> Please Specify:</label>
                <input type="text" name="other" value=" " />
                </div>
          </div><!-- End rowElem -->
            </div><!-- End of ProjectList -->

          <br /><br />
        <div class="row">
         <div id="rowElem" class="col-md-4">
           <ul><li><h5 class="formtitle">Timeframe:</h5></li></ul> 

            <select name="timeFrame" id="timeFrame">
                <option id="normal" value="normal">Normal Pace</option>
                <option id="speedy" value="speedy">Speedy Pace</option>
                <option id="urgent" value="urgent">URGENT Pace</option>
            </select>       


         <div id="extraChargeArea">
              <br /><br />
              <h6 style="color:red">Please note that there will be an extra charge for speedy &#38; urgent.</h6>
            </div>

          </div><!-- End rowElem -->
     <div class="col-md-2">
     <br /><br />
     <img src="img/andsign.png" class="img-responsive" alt="&" />
     </div>

          <div id="rowElem" class="col-md-6">
         <ul><li><h5 class="formtitle">Budget:</h5></li></ul>
                        <select name="budget">
             <option value="Price1">$50 - $100</option>
             <option value="Price2">$100 - $500</option>
             <option value="Price3">$500 - $2,500</option>
             <option value="Price4">$2,500 - $5,000</option>
             <option value="Price5">$5,000 - $10,000</option>
             <option value="Price2">$10,000 +</option>
            </select>               
        <br /><br />
            <h6>Pricing will vary, depending on complexity &#38; timeframe.</h6> 
            <h6 style="color:red">Deposit of 40% required before start date.</h6>

         </div><!-- End rowElem -->
          </div><!-- End of Row -->

            <br />



                <div class="rowElem">
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit!" class="contactbutton btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
                  </div><!-- End rowElem -->


          </form>    
          </div> <!-- End form-wrap -->

     <script type="text/javascript">
        var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-68528-29");
        pageTracker._initData();
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
        </script>         
    </div><!-- End of Primary Col -->
```

JS

```
$(function () {
$('#contactForm').jqTransform().validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function () {
                $('#contactForm').hide();
                $('#form-wrap').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks! Your request has been sent.</p>")
            }
        });
    }
});
$("#emailArea").hide();
$("#phoneArea").hide();
$("#phoneArea").hide();
$("#addWebArea").hide();
$("#addGraphicArea").hide();
$("#addAppArea").hide();
$("#addPresArea").hide();
$("#addOtherArea").hide();
$(".jqTransformRadio").click(function () {
    if ($(".jqTransformRadio").eq(1).attr("class") == "jqTransformRadio jqTransformChecked") {
        $("#phoneArea").slideDown();
        $("#emailArea").hide();
    } else {
        $("#emailArea").slideDown();
        $("#phoneArea").hide();
    }
});
$('.jqTransformCheckbox').click(function () {
    if ($('#addWeb').is(':checked')) {
        $('#addWebArea').show();
    } else {
        $('#addWebArea').hide();
    }
});
$('.jqTransformCheckbox').click(function () {
    if ($('#addGraphic').is(':checked')) {
        $('#addGraphicArea').show();
    } else {
        $('#addGraphicArea').hide();
    }
});
$('.jqTransformCheckbox').click(function () {
    if ($('#addApp').is(':checked')) {
        $('#addAppArea').show();
    } else {
        $('#addAppArea').hide();
    }
});
$('.jqTransformCheckbox').click(function () {
    if ($('#addPres').is(':checked')) {
        $('#addPresArea').show();
    } else {
        $('#addPresArea').hide();
    }
});
$('.jqTransformCheckbox').click(function () {
    if ($('#addOther').is(':checked')) {
        $('#addOtherArea').show();
    } else {
        $('#addOtherArea').hide();
    }
});




$("#extraChargeArea").hide();


$(document).on('change', '#timeFrame', function(){
if($('#normal').is(':selected'))
{$('#extraChargeArea').hide();} 
 else
{$('#extraChargeArea').show();}
});

});
```

PHP

```
<?php

session_start();

function getRealIp() {
   if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {  //check ip from share internet
     $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
   } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {  //to check ip is pass from proxy
     $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
   } else {
     $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   }
   return $ip;
}

function writeLog($where) {

    $ip = getRealIp(); // Get the IP from superglobal
    $host = gethostbyaddr($ip);    // Try to locate the host of the attack
    $date = date("d M Y");

    // create a logging message with php heredoc syntax
    $logging = <<<LOG
        \n
        << Start of Message >>
        There was a hacking attempt on your form. \n 
        Date of Attack: {$date}
        IP-Adress: {$ip} \n
        Host of Attacker: {$host}
        Point of Attack: {$where}
        << End of Message >>
          LOG;
          // Awkward but LOG must be flush left

        // open log file
        if($handle = fopen('hacklog.log', 'a')) {

            fputs($handle, $logging);  // write the Data to file
            fclose($handle);           // close the file

        } else {  // if first method is not working, for example because of wrong file permissions, email the data

            $to = 'ashsquires27@icloud.com';  
            $subject = 'HACK ATTEMPT';
            $header = 'From: support@mcdeavdesigns.com';
            if (mail($to, $subject, $logging, $header)) {
                echo "Sent notice to admin.";
            }

        }
}

function verifyFormToken($form) {

    // check if a session is started and a token is transmitted, if not return an error
    if(!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) { 
        return false;
    }

    // check if the form is sent with token in it
    if(!isset($_POST['token'])) {
        return false;
    }

    // compare the tokens against each other if they are still the same
    if ($_SESSION[$form.'_token'] !== $_POST['token']) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function generateFormToken($form) {

    // generate a token from an unique value, took from microtime, you can also use salt-values, other crypting methods...
    $token = md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));  

    // Write the generated token to the session variable to check it against the hidden field when the form is sent
    $_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = $token; 

    return $token;
}

// VERIFY LEGITIMACY OF TOKEN
if (verifyFormToken('form1')) {

    // CHECK TO SEE IF THIS IS A MAIL POST
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

        // Building a whitelist array with keys which will send through the form, no others would be accepted later on
        $whitelist = array('token','name','email','phone','web','graphics','apps', 'presentation','project','other','timeFrame','budget', 'info');

        // Building an array with the $_POST-superglobal 
        foreach ($_POST as $key=>$item) {

                // Check if the value $key (fieldname from $_POST) can be found in the whitelisting array, if not, die with a short message to the hacker
                if (!in_array($key, $whitelist)) {

                    writeLog('Unknown form fields');
                    die("Hack-Attempt detected. Please use only the fields in the form");

                }
        }



         // PREPARE THE BODY OF THE MESSAGE

        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= 'McDeav Designs Possible Client';
        $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
        $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['name']) . "</td></tr>";

        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";


        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Projects:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['project']) . "</td></tr>";


        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Timeframe:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['timeFrame']) . "</td></tr>";

        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Budget:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['budget']) . "</td></tr>";


        $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Additional Info:</strong> </td><td>" . htmlentities($_POST['info']) . "</td></tr>";
        $message .= "</table>";
        $message .= "</body></html>";




        //  MAKE SURE THE "FROM" EMAIL ADDRESS DOESN'T HAVE ANY NASTY STUFF IN IT

        $pattern = "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i"; 
        if (preg_match($pattern, trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])))) { 
            $cleanedFrom = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email'])); 
        } else { 
            return "The email address you entered was invalid. Please try again!"; 
        } 




        //   CHANGE THE BELOW VARIABLES TO YOUR NEEDS

        $to = 'ashsquires27@icloud.com';

        $subject = 'New Client';

        $headers = "From: " . $cleanedFrom . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
          echo 'Your message has been sent.';
        } else {
          echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
        }

        die();

    }
} else {

    if (!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) {

    } else {
        echo "Hack-Attempt detected. Got ya!.";
        writeLog('Formtoken');
    }

}

    ?>
```

After Head

```
<?php
 // generate a new token for the $_SESSION superglobal and put them in a hidden field
$newToken = generateFormToken('form1');   
 ?>
```

CSS

```
.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a {
display: block;
padding: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
color:#333;
background-color: #FFF;
font-size: 12px;
     }

   .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a.selected {
  background: #EDEDED;
  color: #333;
    }

    .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a:hover, .jqTransformSelectWrapper ul a.selected:hover       {
     background:#3582c4;
    color: #fff;
       }

      /* -------------
      * Hidden - used to hide the original form elements
      * ------------- */
      .jqTransformHidden {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are attaching `click` handler which occurs when the user clicks on an element, instead attach `change` handler which occurs when the value of an element has been changed.Try this:

```
$("#extraChargeArea").hide();

$('#timeFrame').change(function(){
if($('#normal').is(':selected'))
{$('#extraChargeArea').hide();} 
 else
{$('#extraChargeArea').show();}
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Ww2/)

Comment: So it for sure works on the Demo, however I am having trouble getting it to pop up on my site all together now.

Comment: May be you have not included jquery library?use console.log() and check if there is any error..

Comment: Sorry it took so long to post, my baby woke up & I had to lay her back down. Anyways, It does not say there is an error. I have tried switching up the jquery library to a newer version, however I cannot go beyond 1.8. Otherwise it messes up the rest of my form. (& it wouldn't work anyways)

Comment: Your contact form validation code is creating the problem if you remove it works fine..By the way where is form in your html code??

Comment: My apologies, I added the whole code. I have some php at the top of the html document if you need to see that as well let me know.

Comment: Ok added. I really appreciate you taking the time to help with this.

Comment: ok its in my freaking css.... somehow the .jqTransformhidden class is messing it up. ugh I can't believe i forgot to look at this...

Comment: once i take the hidden class out, my form css messes up however if remove that stylesheet altogether the .change works without the style I want for the form though....I will spend more time on it later today, I need to take a break from looking at it, maybe that will help.